# Memory leak when counting the number of occurrences of the user IDs in the user logs

Tags: java, string, file, hashmap

I need to count the number of occurrences of the user IDs in the user logs.
I have 10 log files (each with 2-3 gigabytes). Each file have long lines inside of which I need only one value of the user ID. I wrote the code (see below), unfortunately when I run it, I see a very strong memory usage and get the error "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded".
Help me please correct my code...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Path ptIn = new Path("/user/test");
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
    FileStatus[] lf = fs.listStatus(ptIn);

    LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < lf.length; i++) {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(lf[i].getPath())));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String key = line.split("\\t")[2].intern();

            if (map.containsKey(key)) {
                map.put(key, map.get(key) + 1);
            } else {
                map.put(key, 1);
            }
        }

        br.close();
        br = null;
    }

    Path ptOut = new Path("/user/test/test.result.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(ptOut, true)));

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        bw.write(key + "\t" + map.get(key) + "\n");
    }

    bw.close();
    bw = null;
    map.clear();
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to `intern` the key?

Comment: Do you have to use Java for this? Because a `cat | cut | sort | uniq` command chain would definitely be a lot faster (if you're using some form of Unix).

Comment: @Mureinik I do not know very well java
This is my attempt to solve the problem (here I could be wrong)

Comment: @biziclop Unfortunately (in this area) need java

Comment: @Shamany that doesn't answer Mureinik's question. Why do you call intern()? Where does that idea come from and why do you think it's a good one? Do you understand what intern() does? Have you read its documentation?

Comment: You could the find method to get find the correct substring instead of splitting the lines, which could help reduce heap fragmentation. Also if values get sufficient large (no longer from the `Integer` pool) this could also cause heap fragmentation. Using mutable objects instead of `Integer`s could help in that case.

Comment: @JBNizet I read that this method can be used to solve problems with memory when working with strings, and also when there is a duplicate.
But as I wrote, I could be wrong.
And if remove .intern() the problem remains.

Comment: Do you really need the result HashMap sorted by keys? Your user IDs are not int or long, they contain letters, do they?

Comment: Yes IDs aren't integers and contain letters.
Do you think that the issue in that?

Comment: Which version of Java are you using, and how many unique keys do you expect, and what's the length of the keys?

Comment: @beny23 java 8 and ~20mill unique keys

Answer (score 0):

there are two places, where you can cumulate memory
 - in the map variable - you are putting too many different 'users' to table
 - in the line variable - one of file contains line too long to be stored in memory - do some char by char reading with some 'user' value parser

Comment: To improve your answer please include example on how this can be done. Suggest also how to set memory